# MediaPlayer Error (1, -114)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

I am working on application that contacts with media server. So, I have an array that fills with media's URLs. Media type is `mp3`.

I have a `ListView` that each row indicates one of array's cell. When clicked event received to each row, It should run `setDataSource`, `prepare` and `start` MediaPlayer. When first time, I clicked on one row, All things are okay and media streams successfully. But when I clicked another while last media is playing, `error (1,-114)` occurs.

Based on [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html), I know `setDataSource` should be run in `Idle` state of MediaPlayer, So, before setting data source, I invoke `reset` to move to `Idle` state.

```
    try {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getMusicUrl());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

I implement `OnErrorListener`, The error details is as follows:

`What: 1` [MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN)

`Extra: -114` (I haven't found any docs about this error)

Can any one help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try calling `mediaPlayer.release()` when you decide to switch to other song.

Comment: Calling `release()` will send the player into a state where no other methods should be called. He would need to re-create the `MediaPlayer` at that point (which isn't a terrible idea, but probably not necessary).